# program keeps crashing, other issues with program

Tags: c

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. One of the errors is that rectangle is first being mentioned in int `main()`. I need the program to ask the user for the dimensions of 2 rectangles and do some calcualtions and return those values. I also want it to somehow incorporate the struct names in the header file. thank you

rectangle2.h

```
struct  rectangle
{
    double  length;     // variable to store length
    double  width;      // variable to store width
};

// function to calculate the area
double  area(   struct  rectangle jane  );
// function to calculate the perimeter
double  perimeter( struct  rectangle luis );
// function to calculate the diagonal length from one corner to another
double diagonal( struct  rectangle adrian );
// function to determine if the rectangle is a square
// returns true when it is a square, false when it is not
bool  isSquare( struct  length fernie );
// function to determine whether the rectangle is golden
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_rectangle
//  (a + b) / a  is equal to a / b
// returns true when it is a golden rectangle, false when it is not
bool  isGolden( struct  length claudia );
// function to determine if two rectangles are similar
// two rectangles are similar if the ratio of the length and width of
// one rectangle is equal to the ratio of the length and width of
// the other rectangle
bool areSimilar( struct  rectangle  pedro, struct  rectangle omar );
```

rectangle.c

```
#include "rectangle2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

double area( struct rectangle jane ) //to calculate area of rectangle
{
return jane.width * jane.length;
}

double perimeter( struct rectangle luis ) //to calculate perimeter of rectangle
{
return 2 * ( luis.length + luis.width );
}

double diagonal( struct rectangle adrian ) //to calculate diagonal of rectangle
{
return ( adrian.length * adrian.length ) + ( adrian.width * adrian.width );
}

bool isSquare( struct length fernie  ) //checks if rectangles are square
{
    if( ( fernie.width * fernie.length ) == ( fernie.length * fernie.length ) )
        return true;

    else
        return false;
}

bool isGolden( struct length claudia ) //checks if rectangles are golden
{
if( ( ( claudia.width + claudia.length ) / claudia.width ) == ( claudia.width / claudia.length ) )
return true;

else
return false;
}

bool areSimilar( struct rectangle pedro, struct rectangle omar ) //checks if rectangles are similar
{
if( ( pedro.length / pedro.width ) == ( omar.length / omar.width ) )
return true;

else
return false;
}
```

main.c

```
int main()

{
struct rectangle sides;
sides.length;
sides.width;


//asks the user for the length and width for 2 rectangles
printf( "\nEnter dimensions of Rectangle 1: " );

printf( "\nEnter Length: " );

scanf( "%lf" , sides.length );

printf( "\nEnter Width: " );

scanf( "%lf" , sides.width );
printf( "\nEnter dimensions of Rectangle 2: " );

printf( "\nEnter Length: " );

scanf( "%lf",sides.length );

printf( "\nEnter Width: " );

scanf( "%lf" , sides.width );


//printing statements after all calculations have been made

printf( "\nArea of Rectangle 1 is: %lf" , area( &jane ) );
printf( "\nArea of Rectangle 2 is: %lf",area( rectangle.jane ) );

printf( "\nPerimeter of Rectangle 1: %lf" , perimeter( rectangle.rec1.luis ) );
printf( "\nPerimeter of Rectangle 2: %f",perimeter( rectangle.rec2.luis ) );

printf( "\nDiagonal of Rectangle 1: %lf" , diagonal( rectangle.rec1.adrian ) );
printf( "\nDiagonal of Rectangle 2: %lf" , diagonal( rectangle.rec2.adrian ) );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Keeps crashing" and "other issues" aren't really descriptive. May I refer you to e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ ?

Comment: At a first glance, your program can't even compile: there's a reference to a `jane` variable in `main()`, and a `jane` member of a `rectange` struct, both which don't exist.

Comment: Does not even compile. What's `rectangle.jane` supposed to be in `main()`? There is no variable named `rectangle` in `main()`.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info, i.e. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your code to get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** `gdb`. Your *fix-my-code* question is off-topic here.

Comment: BTW, put the `\n` at end (not start) of `printf` format control strings. Be scared of and avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

your program cannot compile for multiple reasons.

rectangle2.h is mostly ok.

you need to change the parameter of functions isSquare and isGolden from `struct length` to `struct rectangle`, because `struct length` is not defined.

here is a version of the whole file that will work as you've might envisioned it.

`rectangle2.h`

```
typedef enum {false, true = !false} bool;

struct rectangle
{
    double  length;
    double  width;
};

double area(struct rectangle jane);
double perimeter(struct rectangle luis);
double diagonal(struct rectangle adrian);
bool isSquare(struct rectangle fernie);
bool isGolden(struct rectangle claudia);
bool areSimilar(struct rectangle pedro, struct rectangle omar);
```

in `rectangle.c` you don't need to include `stdio.h` as you don't print and scan in that file. you do need to include `math.h` for function diagonal to be mathematically correct. if you have any trouble making it work this way change the function to the way it was, without sqrt().
you'll also need to replace `struct length` with `struct rectangle` in functions isSquare and isGolden to match the prototypes in `rectangle2.h`.

`rectangle.c`

```
#include "rectangle2.h"
#include <math.h>

double area(struct rectangle jane)
{
    return jane.width * jane.length;
}

double perimeter(struct rectangle luis)
{
    return 2 * (luis.length + luis.width);
}

double diagonal(struct rectangle adrian)
{
    return sqrt(adrian.length*adrian.length + adrian.width*adrian.width);
}

bool isSquare(struct rectangle fernie)
{
    return (fernie.width == fernie.length);
}

bool isGolden(struct rectangle claudia)
{
    double p = (claudia.length + claudia.width) / claudia.length;
    double q = claudia.length / claudia.width;
    return p == q;
}

bool areSimilar(struct rectangle pedro, struct rectangle omar)
{
    return (pedro.length / pedro.width) == (omar.length / omar.width);
}
```

and lastly your main.c is the worst. i'm sure you'll figure it out what was wrong with it by looking at my example, but otherwise ask freely.

`main.c`

```
#include "rectangle2.h"
#include <stdio.h>

struct rectangle rect1, rect2;
char *s;

int main()

{
    printf("\nEnter dimensions of Rectangle 1:");
    printf("\nEnter Length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &rect1.length);
    printf("\nEnter Width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &rect1.width);

    printf("\nEnter dimensions of Rectangle 2:");
    printf("\nEnter Length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &rect2.length);
    printf("\nEnter Width: ");
    scanf("%lf", &rect2.width);

    printf("\nArea of Rectangle 1 is: %lf", area(rect1));
    printf("\nArea of Rectangle 2 is: %lf", area(rect2));

    printf("\nPerimeter of Rectangle 1: %lf", perimeter(rect1));
    printf("\nPerimeter of Rectangle 2: %lf", perimeter(rect2));

    s = areSimilar(rect1, rect2) ? "true" : "false";
    printf("\nRectangle 1 & 2 are similar: %s", s);

    s = isSquare(rect1) ? "true" : "false";
    printf("\nRectangle 1 is square: %s", s);

    printf("\nDiagonal of Rectangle 1: %lf" , diagonal(rect1));
    printf("\nDiagonal of Rectangle 2: %lf\n" , diagonal(rect2));

    return 0;
}
```

to make an executable you'll need to compile main.c and rectangle.c, here is an example on a linux terminal: `cc -o rec main.c rectangle.c -lm`.
the switch -lm is there to include the math library. i think the same example in a windows terminal using borland command line compiler would be like this: `bcc32 main.c rectangle.c`.

i hope this helps. sorry, no time to write more at the moment.